# Star rating system created through loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjvT9.png)I have a table that displays a list of recipes from a database. Each recipe stores a rating out of 5. If no ratings has been submitted 'Not yet rated' will display. If a recipe has a rating, for example, 3, I would like 3 stars to appear. I have wrote jquery to try to achieve this but it works for the first recipe and not for the rest. For each recipe, more stars are printed. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```php
if ($avg !=0)
{
  define('RATE_RECIPE_MAX_STAR_RATING', 5);
  $contentitems1 = "<form><div class='stars'>";
  for ($i = 1; $i <= RATE_RECIPE_MAX_STAR_RATING; $i++) 
  {
    //$contentitems1 .= '<input type="radio" style= "display:none;" 
    //$contentitems1 .= '<img class="rate_recipe_star" name="star_' . $i . '" id="star_' . $i . '" src="fadedstar.png" width="25" />';
    $contentitems1 .= '<span class="fa fa-star-o star"  name="star_' . $i . '" id="star_' . $i . '"></span>';
}

"</div></form>";
echo $contentitems1 .="<script type='text/javascript'> paint_the_stars($avg)
</script>";} 
echo '<div class="star_' . $avg . '"></div>'?>
```

```js
function paint_the_stars(howmany) {
  var items = new Array();

  $(".star").each(function() {
    //var star = jQuery(this)
    var star = $(this);
    console.log(star);
    var starno = $(star).attr('id').substring(5);
    console.log(starno);
    //console.log("Star:"+star);

    if (starno <= howmany) {
      //console.log("TRUE PRINT A STAR"+starno);
      //$(this).attr('src', 'yellowstar.png');
      var item = $(this).removeClass("fa-star-o").addClass("fa-star");
      items.push(item);
    } else {
      //return true;
      var item = $(this).removeClass("fa-star").addClass("fa-star-o");
      items.push(item);
    }

    if (starno == 5) {
      $.each(items, function(){
        console.log(this);
        $('.star_'+howmany).append(this);
      });
      return false;
    }   
  })
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working/what does work? We need more information to help you!

Comment: For starters, you have parse errors.

Comment: Could you please show the actual HTML output. It will help to re-create the problem given that the PHP isn't relevant.

Comment: > > > `id="radio_star_'` is an undefined constant. Or, was that just a bad paste?

Comment: I've added an image of what's going on. I can't even think of what's causing the error